# Imageview visibility affected before animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, visibility

I'm working with some animations in my project :

I have my own animated class :

```
public class Anim1Foto implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private ImageView imagen1;
    private ImageView imagen2;

public Anim1Foto (ImageView pimagen1,ImageView pimagen2){
    this.imagen1 = pimagen1;
    this.imagen2 = pimagen2;
}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

    AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagen1, "translationY", 0,200);
    anim.setDuration(2500);


     as.playSequentially(anim);
    as.start();

    imagen1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
}
```

What i want to do is to translate my Imageview and then make it disappear with "setVisibility(INVISIBLE)" but what i'm getting is that the imageview don't appear at all at the beginnig, after making some tests it lead me to the conclusion : the visibility is being affected before the animatorSet start's....I'm guessing wrong? if so what would be a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this:-

```
public class Anim1Foto implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private ImageView imagen1;
    private ImageView imagen2;

public Anim1Foto (ImageView pimagen1,ImageView pimagen2){
    this.imagen1 = pimagen1;
    this.imagen2 = pimagen2;
}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

    AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagen1, "translationY", 0,200);
    anim.setDuration(2500);


     as.playSequentially(anim);
    as.start();

    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                imagen1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
}
```